# apache2.service is masked

Tags: apache2

When I try to restart apache2 by using the command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It gives me this error:

```
Failed to restart apache2.service: Unit apache2.service is masked.
```

Is this a hosting-related problem?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: version 17.04 @George

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading to 18.04. I found the command to unmask the service. But still one thing is not resolved: Why did apache2 get into this masked state? I could not find a reason up to now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A masked service is used to prevent a unwanted start of this service. If you are sure that Apache2 shouldn't be masked, you can just unmask and then restart your service with:

```
sudo systemctl unmask apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: just one thing... how should one be sure if the service should not be masked if the os randomly masked it?

Comment: It's difficult to handle, there are probably many reason why a service is masked. By example if you install samba, some service is masked by default depending the way you wish to start it (as simple folder sharing, or full domain controller).