# Why was the apache2 service masked after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, apache2

I upgraded my server from 16.04 Ubuntu to 18.04.

After running `do-release-upgrade` and rebooting `apache2` was masked.

I used [this Q&A to unmask it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959723/apache2-service-is-masked), but but one question remains: **why was the service masked?**

Comment: Please tell me why if you think this question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Between versions 16.04 and 18.04, `apache2` differs. [16.04 has Apache 2.4.18-2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/apache2) whereas [18.04 has Apache 2.4.29-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/apache2). After running `do-release-upgrade`, Apache will have been upgraded.

Potentially, between 2.4.18-2 and 2.4.29-1 a change could have been made to the configuration file syntax which would cause Apache to fail is unexpected ways, or be configured unsafely. Unfortunately, `do-release-upgrade` doesn't know wether or not this is the case, so it is forced to mask it either way.

For your own safety, the service is masked until you manually re-enable it. The idea is that you verify that your configuration files are still correct, and then you can unmask it.